# cannot resolve symbol "cucumber" in IntelliJ

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am seeing "cannot resolve cucumber" error even after adding "cucumber-java" in my POM

I also have tried adding "junt" to POM, but the issue is not resolved

Answer (score 6):

After spending lot of time, I found the issue with the dependencies in POM. We have to add both "cucumber-java" and "cucumber-junit" to POM.xml in your maven project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```